# Difference between the Apply and OK button

Tags: eclipse, user-interface

What is in the Eclipse preferences the difference between the Apply and OK.

I am using after changing the preferences just the OK button to apply the changes and close the popup while using Apply leaves the popup open.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

"OK" is a combination of "Apply" + closing the window. This is not just an Eclipse thing; most GUI applications (at least under Windows) operate the same way.